# mysqli fetch_object() fatal error

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to use mysqli in for my forum database. this is the code I used:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php


include("config.php");
$limits = "6";
$forum_id = "2"; 

$db = new mysqli($INFO['sql_host'], $INFO['sql_user'], $INFO['sql_pass'], $INFO['sql_database']);


$topics = $db->query("
    SELECT
        `topics`.`start_date`,
        `topics`.`title`,
        `topics`.`starter_name`,
        `topics`.`posts`,
        `topics`.`title_seo`,
        `topics`.`tid`,
        `posts`.`post`
    FROM
        `" . $INFO['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "topics` as `topic`,
        `" . $INFO['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "posts` as `post`
    WHERE
        `topics`.`approved` = 1 AND
        `topics`.`forum_id`= " . $forum_id . " AND
        `posts`.`topic_id` = `topic`.`tid` AND
        `posts`.`new_topic` = 1
    ORDER BY
        `topics`.`start_date`
    DESC LIMIT 5");

echo '<ul id="news">';

while ($topic = $topics->fetch_object()) {


    $url = $INFO['board_url'] . '/index.php?/topic/' . $topic->tid . '-' . $topic->title_seo . '/';


    $topic->post = strip_tags(str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('<', '>'), $topic->post));


    $topic->start_date = date("Y.m.d H:i", $topic->start_date);

    echo '
<div class="news">
<div class="newsp"><div class="pteksts"><a href="'.$url.'">' . $topic->title . '</div></div></a>
<center><img src="img/news.png"></center>
<div class="teksts" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">' . $topic->post . '</div>
</div>

';
}

echo '</ul>';
?>
```

and errors i received:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /home/public_html/scripts/news.php on line 35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give aliases for your tables as `topic` and `post`, but then you use the aliases `topics` and `posts`. You need to change the table qualifiers to use the same spelling as your table alias.

**Wrong, because alias `topic` is not the same as table qualifier `topics`:**

```
SELECT
    `topics`.`start_date`, . . .
FROM
    `" . $INFO['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "topics` as `topic`,
. . .
```

**Right, after changing the table qualifier to match the alias name:**

```
SELECT
    `topic`.`start_date`, . . .
FROM
    `" . $INFO['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "topics` as `topic`,
. . .
```

**Right as well, but alias is unnecessary if it's the same as the base table name:**

```
SELECT
    `topics`.`start_date`, . . .
FROM
    `" . $INFO['sql_tbl_prefix'] . "topics` as `topics`,
. . .
```

But more to the point, you should always check the return value from $db->query(), because it returns **false** if there's an error. You can't call any method on a **false** because that's not an object.

If that happens, report the error but do not try to fetch from the result. It won't work.

```
$topics = $db->query(...);
if ($topics === false) {
    die($db->error);
}

// now we can be sure it's safe to call methods on $topics
while ($topic = $topics->fetch_object()) {
    . . .
```

---

Re your comment that the output is blank:

I just tested this script and it mostly works, so I can't guess what's going wrong. I suggest you read your http server's error log, which is where many PHP notices and errors are output.

I do see the following notice:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /Users/billkarwin/workspace/SQL/22159646.php on line 51
```

The line is this:

```
$topic->start_date = date("Y.m.d H:i", $topic->start_date);
```

The problem is that PHP's [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function takes an integer timestamp, not a date string.

You might want to format the date in SQL, using MySQL [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead.

Comment: Now it says Unknown column 'topics.start_date' in 'field list'

Comment: Sounds like you may have misspelled the column name, too, then. Check to see what column names are used in your table with `SHOW CREATE TABLE prefix_topics` (where prefix is whatever your `$INFO['sql_tbl_prefix']` is).

Comment: the table had no prefix, so i removed $INFO['sql_tbl_prefix'] still showing the same error and tables i checked were spelled correctly

Comment: Is `start_date` a column in your `topics` table or your `posts` table?

Comment: `start_date` is a column in table `topics`

Comment: See example above, where I spell out the reason for the error and show example on how to fix it.

Comment: I've done that and now i am not getting the content i wanted to get and i get no errors just like the script didn't exsist

Comment: Test the query in the mysql client to make sure it actually returns some rows. You might simply have no data that matches the query's conditions.

Comment: i tested query in the mysql client, it sends back data.

Comment: no luck finding the problem.. i guess i need to code a new script.